# Have different sudo and SFTP passwords?

Tags: linux, wordpress, passwords, sftp, sudo

I was just curious if there was a way to have different SFTP and sudo passwords for the same user. I'm using Wordpress on a site that has the FTP password listed in plain text in wp-config.php so that plugins will install correctly (long story), and if the site gets hacked, I don't want to just hand said hacker a password that'd give them root access.

Thanks in advance

P.S:
uname -a gives "Linux *DOMAIN* 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Both are simply using the account's password as stored in /etc/shadow. If you want different passwords, you'll have to use different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If possible (and you're not using shared hosting, which I'm assuming you aren't since you have root access), set "www-data" (or whatever the web server is run as) to the files on the WordPress install, and you should be able to update using some other method (direct file I/O from PHP) instead of FTP